# Inserting a SQL column value that has double quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert a record into my SQL database that has a column value as follows:

```
6" PVC vent 140' S, 4' W of NW crnr of bldg
```

I have tried putting single quotations around at the front and end of this value and I have tried putting double quotations at both the front and end of this value. Both results in an "Incorrect syntax" error. Both ends the value at **140'** and starts the **S**, as another value. I really need to figure this out because I am seeing multiple values like this in the database unfortunately.

Here is my complete `INSERT` statement, the value above is the **SMPL_PT_DESC** column:

```
INSERT INTO CC_MSD_LIMS_STAGING (SMN, FACILITY_ID,SCHEDULE_DATE, IND_NAME, ADDRESS_LINE_1, ADDRESS_LINE_2, CITY, STATE, ZIP, SMPL_PT_DESC, SMPL_PT_NUM, SPLIT, TRUCK_ID, PROJECT_TYPE, SAMPLER, IND_ID, BOTTLE_TYPE, PRESERVATIVE, SAMPLE_TYPE, POLLUTANT, UNITS, SIU_IND, SURCHARGE_IND, SPECIAL_INSTRUCTIONS, AUTOSAMPLER_READY, SHIFT_L, SHIFT_START_TIME, PRIMARY_CONTACT_FIRSTNAME, PRIMARY_CONTACT_LASTNAME, PRIMARY_CONTACT_PHONE, ALTERNATE_CONTACT_FIRSTNAME, ALTERNATE_CONTACT_LASTNAME, ALTERNATE_CONTACT_PHONE, MONITORING_ID) 
VALUES ('1793175', '1037247400', '11/13/2017 12:00:00 AM', 'STONETRENDS LLC', '18092 Chesterfield Airport', '', 'Chesterfield', 'MO', '63005', '6" PVC vent 140' S, 4' W of NW crnr of bldg', '001', 'N', '493', 'IM', 'M', '2464', 'P0', 'None', 'T04', 'T208000', 'mg/L', '', 'Y', '', 'Y', '1', '0700AM', 'Patrick ', 'Martin', '6365371607', 'Stefan ', 'Landgraf', '6365371607', '-1')
```

Comment: You need to escape the single quote by replacing it by two single quotes: `... vent 140''S, 4''W of ...`  Or even better use a parametrized query

Comment: Use backslash and single quote to escape double quotes and single quote respectively. `6\" PVC vent 140'' S, 4'' W of NW crnr of bldg`

Comment: Use a parameterized query with strongly-typed parameters. Not only will that avoid the need to escape quotes, it will handle dates and decimals properly and provide better security.

Comment: Are you just typing this command in a SQL client?

Comment: I got the same result. I used the code below to deal with the escaping:    ~if (col.ColumnName.Equals("SMPL_PT_DESC"))
                            {
                                string smpl_pt = row[col].ToString().Replace("'", "''");
                                smpl_pt = smpl_pt.Replace('"', '\"');
                                cmdText.Append("" + row[col] + "");
                                cmdText.Append("', '");
                            }~

Comment: please excuse my "code". I couldn't get my mini-Markdown correct. The code above produces the same value as what I originally posted. I need for the INSERT sql statement to be able to properly read this. Because as of now it stops at the **S,**

Comment: I wish I could change how the users input these descriptions but this is what I am dealing with.

Comment: @Obie_One So you're programming this using SqlClient's SqlCommand? In that case [*use a parameterised query*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2). There's no need to roll your own escaping.

Comment: I'm generating the INSERT command in a C# application and trying to use a SQLCommand object to execute the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should  write `\"` or `""` ( if use `@` ) instead of `"` for .net compiler and `''` ( double ' ) instead of `'`
for sql server.

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO CC_MSD_LIMS_STAGING (SMN, FACILITY_ID,SCHEDULE_DATE, IND_NAME, ADDRESS_LINE_1, ADDRESS_LINE_2, CITY, STATE, ZIP, SMPL_PT_DESC, SMPL_PT_NUM, SPLIT, TRUCK_ID, PROJECT_TYPE, SAMPLER, IND_ID, BOTTLE_TYPE, PRESERVATIVE, SAMPLE_TYPE, POLLUTANT, UNITS, SIU_IND, SURCHARGE_IND, SPECIAL_INSTRUCTIONS, AUTOSAMPLER_READY, SHIFT_L, SHIFT_START_TIME, PRIMARY_CONTACT_FIRSTNAME, PRIMARY_CONTACT_LASTNAME, PRIMARY_CONTACT_PHONE, ALTERNATE_CONTACT_FIRSTNAME, ALTERNATE_CONTACT_LASTNAME, ALTERNATE_CONTACT_PHONE, MONITORING_ID) VALUES ('1793175', '1037247400', '11/13/2017 12:00:00 AM', 'STONETRENDS LLC', '18092 Chesterfield Airport', '', 'Chesterfield', 'MO', '63005', '6\" PVC vent 140'' S, 4'' W of NW crnr of bldg', '001', 'N', '493', 'IM', 'M', '2464', 'P0', 'None', 'T04', 'T208000', 'mg/L', '', 'Y', '', 'Y', '1', '0700AM', 'Patrick ', 'Martin', '6365371607', 'Stefan ', 'Landgraf', '6365371607', '-1')";
```

or with `@`

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO CC_MSD_LIMS_STAGING (SMN, FACILITY_ID,SCHEDULE_DATE, IND_NAME, ADDRESS_LINE_1, ADDRESS_LINE_2, CITY, STATE, ZIP, SMPL_PT_DESC, SMPL_PT_NUM, SPLIT, TRUCK_ID, PROJECT_TYPE, SAMPLER, IND_ID, BOTTLE_TYPE, PRESERVATIVE, SAMPLE_TYPE, POLLUTANT, UNITS, SIU_IND, SURCHARGE_IND, SPECIAL_INSTRUCTIONS, AUTOSAMPLER_READY, SHIFT_L, SHIFT_START_TIME, PRIMARY_CONTACT_FIRSTNAME, PRIMARY_CONTACT_LASTNAME, PRIMARY_CONTACT_PHONE, ALTERNATE_CONTACT_FIRSTNAME, ALTERNATE_CONTACT_LASTNAME, ALTERNATE_CONTACT_PHONE, MONITORING_ID) 
VALUES ('1793175', '1037247400', '11/13/2017 12:00:00 AM', 'STONETRENDS LLC', '18092 Chesterfield Airport', '', 'Chesterfield', 'MO', '63005', '6"" PVC vent 140'' S, 4'' W of NW crnr of bldg', '001', 'N', '493', 'IM', 'M', '2464', 'P0', 'None', 'T04', 'T208000', 'mg/L', '', 'Y', '', 'Y', '1', '0700AM', 'Patrick ', 'Martin', '6365371607', 'Stefan ', 'Landgraf', '6365371607', '-1')";
```

Comment: Visual Studio won't allow that without adding a closing double